Using Kirchhoff's voltage law for calculating S-parameters
Consider the following circuit:

for which I'd like to calculate the S-parameters of the impedance \$Z\$ (and assuming \$Z_G\$ = \$Z_L\$ = \$Z_0\$). Will it be correct to use the Kirchhoff's voltage law for such purpose?
For example, I'd consider two contours:
$$U_0 = I_1\cdot\left(Z_0+Z+Z_0\right)$$
and
$$U_1 = I_1\cdot\left(Z_0+Z\right)$$
as (I believe) it is done here.
